# Todo list takes 30 seconds to appear

Tags: javascript, angularjs, components

I am using Angular 1.5.8. I have a component within a component. The parent component has a div with `ng-show` that decides when the child component should appear.

The parent component...

```
function ScheduleController() {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.openTodo = function() {
        ctrl.isTodoVisible = true;
    }
}

angular.module('myApp').component('userTodoDisplay', {
    template: `
    <button click="ctrl.$openTodo()"></button>
    <div class="my-todo" ng-show="$ctrl.isTodoVisible">
        <eb-todo schedule-id="$ctrl.selectedScheduleId" connected-to-project="$ctrl.selectedScheduleConnectedToProject"
                 permissions="$ctrl.User.Role" close-click="$ctrl.closeTooltip()"></eb-todo>
    </div>
    `,
    controller: [UserTodoDisplayController]
});
```

The following child component takes almost 30 seconds to appear once I set `isTodoVisible` to `true`.

```
function TodoController() {
    //
}

angular.module('myApp').component('ebTodo', {
    bindings: {
        scheduleId: '<',
        connectedToProject: '<',
        statuses: '<',
        permissions: '<',

        detailsClick: '&',
        printClick: '&',
        editClick: '&',
        shareClick: '&',
        deleteClick: '&',
        copyClick: '&',
        toggleConnectClick: '&',
        setStatusClick: '&',
        closeClick: '&'
    },
    template: `
        <div>
            <button ng-click="$ctrl.closeClick()">Close</button>

            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list" ng-show="$ctrl.permissions.CanViewTask"
                ng-click="$ctrl.detailsClick({data: $ctrl.scheduleId})"></button>

            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" ng-show="$ctrl.permissions.CanViewTask"
                ng-click="$ctrl.printClick({data: $ctrl.scheduleId})"></button>

            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" ng-show="$ctrl.permissions.CanEditTask"
                ng-click="$ctrl.editClick({data: $ctrl.scheduleId})"></button>

            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" ng-show="$ctrl.permissions.CanEditTask"
                ng-click="$ctrl.shareClick({data: $ctrl.scheduleId})"></button>

            <button class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ng-show="$ctrl.permissions.CanDeleteTask"
                ng-click="$ctrl.deleteClick({data: $ctrl.scheduleId});"></button>

            <button ng-show="$ctrl.permissions.CanAddTask"
                ng-click="$ctrl.copyClick({data: $ctrl.scheduleId})">Copy</button>

            <button ng-show="$ctrl.connectedToProject" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleConnectClick({data: $ctrl.scheduleId})">Disconnect</button>
            <button ng-hide="$ctrl.connectedToProject" ng-click="$ctrl.toggleConnectFromTooltip({data: $ctrl.scheduleId})">Connect</button>
        </div>
    `,
    controller: [ScheduleTooltipController]
});
```

I have seen other issues similar to this one on SO, but those issues involved ngAnimate. I am *not* using ngAnimate.

I have created all of my other components the same way I created this one. I am only having trouble getting the component to appear now that I am using `ng-show`. Why does the `ebTodo` component take approx. 30 seconds to appear after I set `isTodoVisible` to `true`?

Comment: The DevTools may be able to help: 1. You could generate a profile. 2. You might be able to hit Pause while the browser is working, so you can see the stack and inspect what work it's doing.

Comment: @joeytwiddle Great idea. Tried it. Looks like the browser did a lot while I was recording, but I'm not sure what to do with this information.

Comment: Are you rendering it inside a ng-repeat? After setting the `isTodoVisible` to true, I would try a `$timeout(function() {$scope.$apply();})`.

Comment: What is in your controller? Sounds like it is doing some long process

Comment: @GregórioKusowski It is not inside an ng-repeat. However, calling `$scope.$apply()` in the `$timeout` fixed the issue. The div appeared immediately. Why do I have to call `$scope.$apply()`? EDIT: I was not using $scope in my components until just now, when I injected $scope so I could do $scope.$apply.

Comment: @Targaryen, it usually happens when you set a property out of the Angular cycle. Like a "raw" `setTimeout`/callback/resolve instead of `$timeout` or `$q` for example. We had some cases where using an external API like Google Maps caused this.

Comment: @GregórioKusowski Perhaps angular components "happen" outside of the regular angular cycle?

Comment: @Targaryen I don't know much about the internals of the dirty checking/etc, but since even native Promises aren't recommended (the `$q` is linked with the angular cycle), I believe that living outside the cycle can be dangerous.

Comment: The phrase *angular components "happen" outside of the regular angular cycle* makes no sense. `isTodoVisible` value is set asynchronously outside of digest cycle, it's as simple as that. Since you don't show where this happens, the question can't get a satisfying answer.

Comment: @estus Actually, `isTodoVisible` is set to true when you click the Todo button. This is a synchronous action.

Comment: It would be 'synchronous' if scope property would be assigned on directive compilation. Otherwise it is asynchronous. And thus needs to be wrapped with `$scope.$apply()`.

Comment: @estus OK that sounds interesting. In a component, I don't actually use `scope` directly. However, since components are just directive sugar, I guess I am actually using `scope`? Maybe component `bindings` are essentially the same thing as directive `scope`? However, I'm still not entirely sure how to resolve the issue other than using `$scope.apply()`. Do I have any other options?

Comment: Please, show in the question where exactly isTodoVisible is set. Yes, components use scope because it is how Angular was built, and yes, you need to use $scope.apply(). This is exactly why it is there.

Comment: @estus Thanks for the comments. I have updated my post with the code you requested.

Comment: I guess you mean `<button onclick=...` Just use `ng-click` instead of `onclick`. All that `ng-click` does is wrapping event listener with `$apply`, it exists for cases like that.

Comment: @estus OK. I had a lot more code than what I posted here so the solution involved more than just the one button, but the way you explained `$scope.$apply()` resolved my issue. Post your answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are digest-aware alternatives to common asynchronous operations in Angular. For click events in templates `ng-click` directive is convenient:

```
<button ng-click="$ctrl.openTodo()">
```

For callbacks that are asynchronously called from places that aren't aware of scope digests (third-party code), a digest should be triggered manually with scope `$apply` method:

```
ctrl.openTodo = function() {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        ctrl.isTodoVisible = true;
    });
}
```

This approach may be incompatible with digest-aware callers (e.g. `ng-click`). Digest cycle will be triggered twice and result in `$rootScope:inprog Action Already In Progress` error.

To safely trigger digest in both digest-aware and digest-unaware calling contexts, `$evalAsync` method can be used instead:

```
ctrl.openTodo = function() {
    $scope.$evalAsync(function () {
        ctrl.isTodoVisible = true;
    });
}
```